# if else condition not working

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have no idea about this code because if the condition is true msgbox will appear but if condition false the msgbox not appear.could anyone give some idea. here is the code

```
 Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Spec WHERE  Category='1BK' IN ( Silo = '" & txtBin.Text & "' AND WheatType = '" & ddlType.Text & "')"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cnnOLEDB)
        cnnOLEDB.Open()
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        'If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        While dr.Read()
            If ddlType.Text = dr("WheatType") Then
                MsgBox("OK")
            Else
                MsgBox("Wrong")
            End If
        End While
```

Comment: Hello Sql Injection vulnerability

Answer (score 1):

You will never see the "Wrong" message if the WheatType is not in the database, because in that case the first call to dr.Read() will return False... there will be no records, and your `If ddlType.Text = dr("WheatType")`condition is never even evaluated.

More than that, though, we have a **serious security issue** here. You **must not** use string concatenation to put user-entered data into your sql command like that.

Try this instead:

```vb
'Your WHERE clause looks wrong, too, but I don't know enough about what you're doing to correct it
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Spec WHERE Category='1BK' IN (Silo= ? AND WheatType= ? )"

Using cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString), _
      cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, cnnOLEDB)

    'Have to guess at parameter types and lengths here
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Bin", OleDbType.Char, 10).Value = txtBin.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Type", OleDbType.Char, 3).Value = ddlType.Text

    cnnOLEDB.Open()
    Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        Dim Found As Boolean = False
        While dr.Read()
            If ddlType.Text = dr("WheatType") Then
                MsgBox("OK")
                Found = True
            End If
        End While
        If Not Found Then MsgBox("Wrong")
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   While dr.Read()
        If ddlType.Text = dr("WheatType").ToString() Then
            MsgBox("OK")
        Else
            MsgBox("Wrong")
        End If
    End While
```

Comment: are you sure the condition will be false ? can you post dr("WheatType") result and ddlType.Text that you enter ?

Comment: if i enter ASW it msgbox appear OK because i have ASW in my database table but if i enter APW the msgbox didn't appear, APW is not in my database table

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested to make sure that

> ddlType.Text = dr("WheatType")

is not true for every row in your table?

Answer (score 0):

if the search string is not exist in your database then the code inside dr.Read() is not working as dr is empty. So you have to change your code like this

```
Dim Found As Boolean = False
        While dr.Read()
            If ddlType.Text = dr("WheatType") Then
                MsgBox("OK")
                Found = True
            End If
        End While
        If Found = False Then
                MsgBox("Wrong")
            End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using String.Compare and Trim:

```
String.Compare(ddlType.Text.Trim(), dr("WheatType").ToString().Trim(), True)
```

If this doesn't work, I imagine these values do not equal.

Good luck.